# Error installing MvvmCross.Forms.Presenter

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I'm not able to install MvvmCross.Forms.Presenter in Xamarin Forms project.

I'm getting following error:

```
Error       Could not install package 'MvvmCross.Forms.Presenter 4.4.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.            0
```

My selected profile is:

[image]

It installs on platform projects (iOS, Android & UWP) but not on Xamarin Forms PCL project.

Which targets should I choose to make it compatible?

Xamarin Forms 2.3.3.180

Answer (score 1):

It's working now.

I changed my profile to as shown below:
[image]

Comment: Just for completeness - the reason for this is that the support for Silverlight is not part of the PCL profile 7, which is declared for this project - see line 16 of https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross-Forms/MvvmCross.Forms.Presenter.Core/MvvmCross.Forms.Presenter.Core.csproj